# IE blocking JQuery on the first time page load

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am uploading a script on a CEWP which uses JQUERY.
The code does not execute on the first time It is loaded in IE. as pop up bow appears at the bottom of the page pormting the end user if he wants to allow blocked content..only when checked, that the page reloads..and the script gets executed

Is there a way to avoid this and have the blocked content enabled form the start

Thank you
Julia

Comment: We need more info, possibly see the HTML for the page. Why is your jQuery blocked?  Where are you getting the jQuery code from? Your own server?  Google CDN? Is your site using `https` and your jQuery source `http`?

Comment: Here is the Script                                           <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var selected = $("select[title = 'ORB Scheduling Status']").val();
if(selected == "Requested") { 
  $("TABLE.ms-formtable>TBODY>TR:eq(3)").css('display', 'none');
  $("TABLE.ms-formtable>TBODY>TR:eq(4)").css('display', 'none');
  }
});</script>
As for my site, yes it is an Https. it's a SharePoint Online Team Site.

Comment: Yep, then that's the problem.  You need to make sure that your jQuery include also uses `https`.  See Kevin's answer below.

Comment: Thank you Steve! it was the https issue as I was referencing JQuery with HTTP..Working great now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you always include your scripts with the same protocol as your domain. to do this automatically, use a protocol-relative url.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note, this won't work if you're working from the file system, for example, `file://mypage.html`

Comment: That solved it, it was the protocol indeed. Thank you Kevin !